# Best method for simple GET based Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get

Im trying to understand the best method for creating a basic Rails app that is only interfaced with via GET values in the url. Im attempting to understand how to go about starting to write logic for this as well as generally where i would want to start coding. Would this main interface code be considered a helper? or should i migrate the code to the model?

An example of how i'd like to use this app is something like the following.

```
http://www.railsapp.com/?order_number=123&print_label=true
```

With this example url i hope to grab the `order_number` get some information from it, determine if `print_label` is true/false and output something to the user.

Im not looking for someone to write it all for me, i'm simply needing some guidance on the best structure on writing a rails app that is only interfaced with via a URL as well as the easiest method for gather GET values.

Comment: You really need to learn more about making a RESTful or Recourse API.

Comment: get values will come through `params` eg. `params[:order_number] #=> 123`. Are you looking to write an `API` or some sort of single page app? Otherwise you might want to read up on [`REST routing`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) as it applies to rails. Also possibly a framework like Sinatra might be more useful to you.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't this basically how all Rails apps work? You configure the routes, Rails sends the params to the controller, and you render something based on those params.

Comment: thanks for the comments @TamerShlash, engineersmnky and Ajedi32 | All i need was a little direction and between you 3 i now have a more confirmed idea on what i need to do. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the 3 comments on the first post i am going to looking into Restful routing and by that gather my params to interact with them.